# jQuery Validate multiple fields on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate multiple fields in a form submit with jQuery, but I cannot get it work. Can someone help me with this?

```
// Validate checkout fields submit
$( '#checkout-data' ).submit( function( event ) {

    $.each( '#checkout-data .required', function(){
        if( this.value.length < 1 ) {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'valid' ).addClass( 'invalid' );
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$( '#checkout-data' ).submit( function( event ) {

    $.each( '#checkout-data .required', function(){
        if( this.value.length < 1 ) {
            $( this ).removeClass( 'valid' ).addClass( 'invalid' );
        }
    });

    if ($('#checkout-data .required.invalid').length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("invalid");

    }
});
```